# Initialising ' ... *__strong' with an expression of incompatible type 'id<UIApplicationDelegate> _Nullable'

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have just updated my copy of Xcode and find that I now have lots of warnings. I am struggling to get the following one sorted out though:

```
ObAppDelegate *appdelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
```

causes this warning:

> Initializing `ObAppDelegate *__strong` with an expression of
>   incompatible type `id<UIApplicationDelegate> _Nullable`

Can anyone point me in the right direction to fix this warning? For information this is the related code used prior to the problem line:

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext *) managedObjectContext {
    return [(ObAppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];
}
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You have:

```
ObAppDelegate *appdelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
```

This will give a warning:

> Initializing `ObAppDelegate *__strong` with an expression of incompatible type `id<UIApplicationDelegate> _Nullable`

Rewrite as:

```
ObAppDelegate *appdelegate = (ObAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
```

That will eliminate the warning.

Comment: Thanks. Spot on. Are you able to help me understand why this warning has just started appearing with my updated version of xcode? This, and a lot of other warnings, has just started appearing since the update.

Comment: You didn't say what version of Xcode you updated from. But you can take it as a rule of thumb that new warnings are simply added as time goes by. Look on them as a blessing; the compiler is just helping you make sure you aren't making some accidental mistake.